# Linear algebra: Direct sum decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

> Let $V$, $W$ be $F$-vector spaces such that $V$ has a direct sum decomposition $V= U_1+U_2$. Let $F_1: U_1 → W$ and $F_2: U_2 → W$ be two linear maps. We say $F : V → W$ is a common extension of $F_1$ and $F_2$ if $F$ agrees with $F_1$ on $U_1$ and $F$ agrees with $F_2$ on $U_2$. Show that there is a common extension $F : V → W$ of $F_1$ and $F_2$.

I am confused as to the idea of the direct sum decomposition. Does it just mean that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are linearly independent? And then if $F_1(U_1) = W$ and $F_2(U_2) = W$ then wouldn't $F(V)$ be $2W$? I am confused. Thank you for the help.

Comment: $U_1$ and $U_2$ are subspaces. What do you mean by saying "$U_1$ and $U_2$ are linearly independent?" ?
Vectors are linearly independent, not subspaces. I think you are using wrong terminology.

Comment: @spkakkar Linear independence of subspaces is used with the obvious definition at least on p.7 in these notes https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/lin-alg/notes.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Direct sum means that we can write $V = U_1 \bigoplus U_2 $ where the only vector in common to $U_1, U_2$ is $0$.

Comment: how would you use that to show there is a common extension?

Comment: Show that you can construct $F$ such that $F = F_1$ on $U_1$ and $F= F_2$ on $U_2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still so lost and not really sure how to proceed and make an attempt. How do you show you can construct F that way? I am really trying but every time I look at this question I am not sure what to do.